# Error when import flat file into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to import a flat file .csv into SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio. My process is:

- Right-click the Database
- Choose Task > Import Flat File

The .csv file contains more than 1100 columns with the size of 36KB . However, SQL Server warns

> Sum of the columns' FillWeight values cannot exceed 65535. (System.Windows.Forms)

How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the configured line delimiters and the actual file encoding yet? Likely it's not reading in the file data correctly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning the .csv file still open correctly on Excel, the file has lots of blank columns